# How to prove a Convergent sequence with $\lim _{n→∞}$

Tags: analysis

Let $\{c_n\}$ be a convergent sequence with  $\lim _{n→∞}c_n$ = 1. Show that there exists N ∈ $\mathbb N$ with n ≥ N we have $c_n$ ≥ 3/4.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know what it means to say that a sequence converges to $1$?

Comment: I am not really where sure where to even start

Comment: Start with the definition.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall the definition of limit for $\lim _{n\to\infty}c_n=1$

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists N \quad \forall n\ge N \quad |c_n-1|\le\epsilon$$

and then select $0<\epsilon\le\frac14$.